# How to remove hyperlink style using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I was able to disable hyperlink using

```
PDActionHide actionshow = new PDActionHide();
actionshow.setH(true);
```

However I want to remove blue colour hyperlink but keep the text. How do I do this using Apache PDFBox?

Answer (score 0):

Do this (works only if the line is part of the annotation and not of the content stream):

```
PDAnnotationLink txtLink = ...
txtLink.setBorderStyle(null);
txtLink.setBorder(new COSArray());
```

this removes the border style and sets an empty color.

Comment: Many thanks.Tried this but no luck. I guess it is part of content stream. With content stream is there anyway?

Comment: Please share the PDF file so I can have a look with PDFDebugger. It's possible with the content stream but it's much more difficult and there is no general solution.